# AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'AboutDialogInfo'

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use wxPython 4.0.0b1 GTK2 (Phoenix) on Ubuntu 16.04 with python3.5. I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'AboutDialogInfo'.
```

The code is pretty straightforward with no complexity.

Comment: Attach your code

Comment: @PreethamSridhar, please check the appropriate demo sample from wxPython site.

Comment: See https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html for the new location of that widget and other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
aboutInfo = wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo()
```

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo.html#wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo